# References can empty after compiling and bibtexing with texStudio

Tags: bibtex

I compiled my .tex file, .bib is in the same folder, and I get empty references after "References"
What is going on here?

Trying to do the same in overleaf, i get this message:

Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

But, I have included:

```
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

So, I can not deduce where the error comes from...

Update: including the `\nocite{*}` label, Overleaf DOES compile and produce the references, but not in local on my Machine with TexStudio...

Comment: do you have any `\cite`  commands?

Comment: I added the \nocite{*} command, but it works in Overleaf, but it does NOT work in local TeXStudio on my computer. Why?

Comment: you need to run pdflatex , bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex (overleaf does that for you using latexmk)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But TeXStudio has no button for pdflatex, bibtex or pdflatex, ...I saw and in the Preferences it seems ok. What am I doing bad? I am clicking ...Ah, I got it!!! Thanks...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you!!!! I was getting crazy with the no references AND the no cap and I managed to solve it...